# How to insert null value to NOT NULL column using the DEFAULT Constraint

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

These is my **example** table definition:

```
CREATE TABLE [MyTable] 
(
    [ColumnName] [bit] NOT NULL
)

ALTER TABLE [MyTable] ADD DEFAULT ((0)) FOR [ColumnName]
```

I want to be able to pass a `Null` value to my stored procedure's `@ColumnValue`, something like:

```
@ColumnValue = null;

INSERT INTO [MyTable] ([ColumnName])
VALUES (@ColumnValue)
```

But I'm getting this error:

> "Cannot insert the value NULL into column... INSERT fails with"

Why the `DEFAULT` constraints not working?

Comment: The default value will be inserted if the requested insert doesn't specify a value for the field.  You're specifying NULL for that field.  If possible, modify your insert to exclude the field entirely, or modify the application doing the insert to be aware of and supply the default value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Solved:

as @J.D. Pace said: The default value will be inserted only if the value is not specified on the `Insert` statement.

so as @dotNET suggested, i have specified the default value in the `INSERT` query statement using the `ISNULL`:

> **ISNULL** - The SQL Server ISNULL() function lets you return an alternative value when an expression is NULL:

```
@ColumnValue = null;

INSERT INTO [MyTable] (
    [ColumnName]
)
VALUES (
    ISNULL(@ColumnValue, 0)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

A table with only one column of `bit` type with a default value seems to be a bad design. This stuff can almost certainly be stored in a different and better way. On the other hand, if there are other columns in the table that you didn't include in the post, just skip this particular column in your `INSERT` query and it will work fine. Lastly, you can specify the default value in your `INSERT` query too.

Comment: it is only example, I can't skip the column because it's value passed to my stored procedure's parameter

Comment: Can't you use an `IF/ELSE` in your SP, using two different queries in case the passed parameter is NULL or non-NULL.